# How did Galfa make Maria temporarily lose her powers?

Tags: junketsu-no-maria

In episode 9 of *Maria the Virgin Witch*, Maria temporarily lost her powers after she was beaten by Galfa.

How did he make them go away for only a slight amount of time without taking her virginity?

Comment: She was first drugged with the incense, then she got punched to the point she lost her control over most of her magic, iirc.

Comment: Being beaten up wouldn't make her unable to use magic.  Otherwise she wouldn't have been able to use magic while fighting the archangel.

Comment: I think it is a combination of the drug, and the fact that she was beaten up. She probably somehow or another lost control to her magic during the process.

Answer (score 1):

When I watched the anime long ago, I also had the same question and discussed it in online forums. There were mainly 2 opinions regarding this.

First was that Galfa only beats her up and pretends to sexually assault Maria, and combined with the smoke drug it makes Maria think that she has lost her virginity, sort of like a mental block.

The second, more crude theory was that he actually did violate her, but uhh..only with the finger of his artificial metal hand so it did not count as losing her virginity.

I prefer to believe that it was the first.

Answer (score 0):

If you pause the scene, you can clearly see that he is raping her. She has no underwear on and he would not have his waist pressed against Maria's if he was using his metal fingers (which is still very sick).

No, the reality is that he drugs Maria, then proceeds to bound, gag, and torture her in the most despicable and diabolical way. That's the harsh truth of how Maria loses her magic.

[image]